# Value of type 'ViewController' does not conform to 'ChartViewDelegate' in assignment

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I'm using charts api, and getting this error

Value of type 'ViewController' does not conform to 'ChartViewDelegate' in assignment

```
class RiseAndFallViewController: UIViewController,ChartViewDelegate {
    func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: Highlight) {
        print("")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var RiseAndFall: HorizontalBarChartView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        RiseAndFall.delegate = self
    }
}
```

this is my code, and I'm getting above error, could you help me?

Comment: implement the `ChartViewDelegate` delegate method on your Current class

Comment: it uses delegate of charts, I'm new to swift, could you help me?
@ThreeCoins

Comment: if you are talking of this protocol: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Charts/2.1.3/Protocols/ChartViewDelegate.html there are 4 functions, in your snippet you implement just "chartValueSelected", can be this the problem?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini